# Strange error when execute httpclient

Tags: java, android, httprequest, httpclient

> I have created an http request in my project. I sat it but didn't work
>   so simplified that part to test it: This is it:

```
HttpClient cl = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = cl.execute(new HttpGet("http://www.google.com"));
        System.out.println(httpResponse.getEntity().getContentLength());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("didn't work!");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

But when I run it I get these:

```
07-21 15:57:36.203  26851-26851/com.akgradev.upbman W/﹕ Unable to open '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': No such file or directory
07-21 15:57:36.203  26851-26851/com.akgradev.upbman W/art﹕ Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error
```

> And of course a "Didn't work!" and a "null" for prints! I appreciate
>   your tips Tnx

Comment: The exception is pretty weird. Could you pls paste your complete code. That may help to get insight. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide complete exception stack trace?

Comment: I don't get it! Made a new project with just one button (!) to get google.com's content length and still have  the same problem! The code is exactly this(Above). Gave it to onClickListener of a button

Comment: Stacktrace: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11914142)

Comment: The above code works on another thread but still have that 2 lines in the logcat

Comment: Try to use any background thread for network operation.if your running in emulator it will show some logs like you mentioned it haven't belongs to your application.See it's belongs to some FM RADIO /`system`/framework/`qcom.fmradio`.jar also you can see it locating to system path

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, except the file it's complaining about is '/system/framework/com.qti.location.sdk.jar'

Comment: I am also facing the same problem in marshmallow device any solution?

Comment: Facing the exact same issue and file. No idea where it's supposed to be located ;) Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of `HttpClient` being deprecated?

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Your exceptions may be the result of the API no longer being supported.